# Translate "Algorithm" in the caption

Tags: algorithms, languages, algorithmicx

This is my code

```
\begin{algorithm}  
\caption{Funkcija ACO}  
\label{alg:aco}  
\begin{algorithmic}  
    \STATE{do something}  
\end{algorithmic}  
\end{algorithm}
```

it produces a caption like this
[image]

I want to translate the word "Algorithm" to my language.. how can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to modify `\ALG@name` in order to get the appropriate translation:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algorithmic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{AlGoRiThM}
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{List of \ALG@name s}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Funkcija ACO}
\label{alg:aco}  
\begin{algorithmic} 
  \STATE{do something}  
\end{algorithmic}  
\end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

You may also consider using the more advanced [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) bundle.

Comment: that's it, tnx.
i will use the algorithmicx too.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\floatname` command in the `algorithm` package. For renaming the algorithm caption.

```
\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithmus}
```

Comment: Instead of posting this as a question, rather provide the code that shows how to use `\floatname`.