# Algorithms and amsart

Tags: algorithms, document-classes, amsart, algorithmic

Basically, I have copied the code from an answer to [this quesiton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60088/translate-algorithm-in-the-caption), for I have to translate some words. I have only changed `documentclass` from `article` to `amsart`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algorithmic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{AlGoRiThM}
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{List of \ALG@name s}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Funkcija ACO}
\label{alg:aco}  
\begin{algorithmic} 
  \STATE{do something}  
\end{algorithmic}  
\end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

Now, I get a bunch of errors:

```
error line 5: Missing } inserted \listofalgorithms
error line 5: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup \listofalgorithms
error line 1: Undefined control sequence ...berline {1}{\ignorespaces Funkcija ACO}}{1}
error line 1: Missing number, treated as zero ...berline {1}{\ignorespaces Funkcija ACO}}{1}
error line 1: Undefined control sequence ...berline {1}{\ignorespaces Funkcija ACO}}{1}
error line 1: Missing number, treated as zero ...berline {1}{\ignorespaces Funkcija ACO}}{1}
warning line 0:  Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

If the line `\listofalgorithms` is omitted, everything works fine (but then, of course, I will not have a list of algorithms).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to make additional provisions for the list of algorithms with AMS classes:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algorithmic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms

\makeatletter
\def\listofalgorithms{\@starttoc{loa}\listalgorithmname}
\def\l@algorithm{\@tocline{0}{3pt plus2pt}{0pt}{1.9em}{}}
\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{AlGoRiThM}
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{List of \ALG@name s}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Funkcija ACO}
\label{alg:aco}  
\begin{algorithmic} 
  \STATE{do something}  
\end{algorithmic}  
\end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]