# Translate "Algorithm" in the caption in beamer

Tags: beamer, xepersian

I use the `algorithmic` and `algorithm` packages for algorithms in `Beamer` and I want to translate the word "Algorithm" in the caption as in [this Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60088/translate-algorithm-in-the-caption/644341?noredirect=1#comment1605671_644341).

This solution doesn't work in `Beamer`.

Comment: The question you linked provides several solutions. Which ones did you try? Please provide a MWE so that people can see what packages you use and what you tried. Also, "doesn't work" isn't a useful description: what doesn't work? Is there an error message?

Comment: Since you tagged your question with xepersian, I'm assuming that's what you are using. Xepersian already translates "algorithm" to Persian based on the context, so it should work, unless there is a clash with something or a version problem. Need a mwe to find the problem.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example so we can see how you use your algorithm packages, which options you use etc.